# gcc arm inline assembler %e0 and %f0 operand modifiers for 16-byte NEON operands?

Tags: gcc, arm, inline-assembly, neon

Found the following inline assembler `code` to calculate the vector cross product :

```
float32x4_t cross_test( const float32x4_t& lhs, const float32x4_t& rhs )
{
    float32x4_t result;

    asm volatile(
    "vext.8 d6, %e2, %f2, #4 \n\t"          
    "vext.8 d7, %e1, %f1, #4 \n\t"  
    "vmul.f32 %e0, %f1, %e2  \n\t" 
    "vmul.f32 %f0, %e1, d6   \n\t" 
    "vmls.f32 %e0, %f2, %e1  \n\t" 
    "vmls.f32 %f0, %e2, d7   \n\t" 
    "vext.8 %e0, %f0, %e0, #4    "      
    : "+w" ( result )                  
    : "w" ( lhs ), "w" ( rhs )            
    : "d6", "d7" );

    return result;
}
```

What do the modifiers  `e` and `f` after `'%'` mean (e.g. `%e2`)? I can not find any reference for this.

This is the assembler code generated by gcc:

```
vext.8 d6, d20, d21, #4 
vext.8 d7, d18, d19, #4 
vmul.f32 d16, d19, d20  
vmul.f32 d17, d18, d6   
vmls.f32 d16, d21, d18  
vmls.f32 d17, d20, d7   
vext.8 d16, d17, d16, #4
```

I now understood the meaning of the used modifiers. Now I tried to follow the cross product algorithm. For this I added some additional comments to the assembler code but the result is not equal to my expectation:

```
    // History:
    // - '%e'  = lower register part
    // - '%f'  = higher register part
    // - '%?0' = res = [ x2 y2 | z2 v2 ]
    // - '%?1' = lhs = [ x0 y0 | z0 v0 ]
    // - '%?2' = rhs = [ x1 y1 | z1 v1 ]
    // - '%e0'       = [ x2 y2 ]
    // - '%f0'       = [ z2 v2 ]
    // - '%e1'       = [ x0 y0 ]
    // - '%f1'       = [ z0 v0 ]
    // - '%e2'       = [ x1 y1 ]
    // - '%f2'       = [ z1 v1 ]
    // Implemented algorithm:
    // |x2|   |y0 * z1 - z0 * y1|
    // |y2| = |z0 * x1 - x0 * z1|
    // |z2|   |x0 * y1 - y0 * x1|
    asm (
    "vext.8 d6, %e2, %f2, #4 \n\t" // e2=[ x1 y1 ], f2=[ z1 v1 ] -> d6=[ v1 x1 ]
    "vext.8 d7, %e1, %f1, #4 \n\t" // e1=[ x0 y0 ], f1=[ z0 v0 ] -> d7=[ v0 x0 ]
    "vmul.f32 %e0, %f1, %e2  \n\t" // f1=[ z0 v0 ], e2=[ x1 y1 ] -> e0=[ z0 * x1, v0 * y1 ]
    "vmul.f32 %f0, %e1, d6   \n\t" // e1=[ x0 y0 ], d6=[ v1 x1 ] -> f0=[ x0 * v1, y0 * x1 ]
    "vmls.f32 %e0, %f2, %e1  \n\t" // f2=[ z1 v1 ], e1=[ x0 y0 ] -> e0=[ z0 * x1 - z1 * x0, v0 * y1 - v1 * y0 ] = [ y2, - ]
    "vmls.f32 %f0, %e2, d7   \n\t" // e2=[ x1 y1 ], d7=[ v0 x0 ] -> f0=[ x0 * v1 - x1 * v0, y0 * x1 - y1 * x0 ] = [  -, - ]
    "vext.8 %e0, %f0, %e0, #4    " // 
    : "+w" ( result )              // Output section: 'w'='VFP floating point register', '+'='read/write'
    : "w" ( lhs ), "w" ( rhs )     // Input section : 'w'='VFP floating point register'
    : "d6", "d7" );                // Temporary 64[bit] register.
```

Comment: this is inline assembly not real assembly, not going to find it in the arm documentation.  What does the rest of your C code look like?

Comment: I added the complete C function. It compiles fine with gcc.

Comment: Legacy FPA registers f0-f7.

Comment: Floating point registers f0 .. f7

Comment: you can check the disassembly then change one check the disassembly, see what changes as a result.

Comment: The FPA architecture has eight floating-point registers, f0-f7, each of which may hold a value of single, double or
extended precision. We name these registers s0-s7, d0-d7 and e0-e7, according to their precision, noting that s0,
d0, e0, and f0 designate the same register.

Comment: so that was 5 minutes on google.

Comment: I added the corresponding gcc output.

Comment: Ok, so s0, d0, e0...reference the same register. But what does this line of code then do: 'vext.8 d6, %e2, %f2, #4' ? I apologize..what was the google keyword you were looking for. I didn´t find anything.

Comment: VEXT (Vector Extract) extracts 8-bit elements from the bottom end of the second operand vector and the top end of the first, concatenates them, and places the result in the destination vector. See Figure 6 for an example.

Comment: %e2 -> d20, %f2 -> d21.  so it is vext.8 d6, d20, d21, #4

Comment: VEXT{cond}.8 {Dd}, Dn, Dm, #imm

Comment: Dd, Dn, Dm
specifies the destination register, the first operand register, and the second operand register, for a doubleword operation.

Comment: imm
is the number of 8-bit elements to extract from the bottom of the second operand vector, in the range 0-7 for doubleword operations, or 0-15 for quadword operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, this is weird.  `result` isn't initialized before the asm statement, but it's used as an input/output operand with `"+w" ( result )`.  I think `"=w" (result)` would be better.  It also makes no sense that this is `volatile`; the output is a pure function of the inputs with no side effects or dependency on any "hidden" inputs, so the same inputs will give the same result every time.  Thus, omitting `volatile` would allow the compiler to CSE it and hoist it out of loops if possible, instead of forcing it to re-compute every time the source runs it with the same inputs.

---

I couldn't find any reference either; the gcc manual's Extended ASM page only documents [operand modifiers for x86](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#x86Operandmodifiers), not ARM.

But I think we can see the operand modifiers do from looking at the asm output:

`%e0` is substituted with `d16`, `%f0` is substituted with `d17`.  `%e1` is `d18` and `%f1` is `d19`.  `%2` is in `d20` and `d21`

Your inputs are 16-byte NEON vectors, in `q` registers.  In ARM32, the upper and lower half of each `q` register is separately accessible as a `d` register.  (Unlike AArch64 where each s / d register is the bottom element of a different q reg.)  It looks like this code is taking advantage of this to shuffle for free by using 64-bit SIMD on the high and low pair of `float`s, after doing a 4-byte `vext` shuffle to mix those pairs of floats.

**`%e[operand]` is the low `d` register of an operand, `%f[operand]` is the high `d` register.**  They're not documented, but the gcc source code says (in `arm_print_operand` in [`gcc/config/arm/arm.c#L22486`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/38cf91e5dc816a7e00fba5d6888c08b2ee398f59/gcc/config/arm/arm.c#L22486):

> These two codes print the low/high doubleword register of a Neon quad
>       register, respectively.  For pair-structure types, can also print
>       low/high quadword registers.

I didn't test what happens if you apply these modifiers to 64-bit operands like `float32x2_t`, and this is all just me reverse-engineering from one example.  But it makes perfect sense that there would be modifiers for this.

x86 modifiers include one for the low and high 8 bits of integer registers (so you can get AL / AH if your input as in EAX), so partial-register stuff is definitely something that GNU C inline asm operand modifiers can do.

---

**Beware that undocumented means unsupported**.

Comment: "only documents operand modifiers for x86" - And not everyone was in favor of doing even that (despite how essential they are!).  For crazy people who want to use undocumented (aka unsupported) features, reading the [source](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/config/arm/arm.c) we see: *These two codes print the low/high doubleword register of a Neon quad register, respectively.  For pair-structure types, can also print low/high quadword registers.*  FWIW.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd: Thanks, I poked around in that directory on github, but searching on `modif` didn't get me anywhere.  And obviously `e` isn't a useful search term.  But yeah, found it at https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/38cf91e5dc816a7e00fba5d6888c08b2ee398f59/gcc/config/arm/arm.c#L22486.  (Your link is to a changelog)

Comment: The trick isn't searching for `e`, it's searching for `'e'`.  And the link is to gcc's SVN.  Using the download link gets you the latest from trunk.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the meaning of `%e0` & `%f0`, this topic is very helpful. The `cross_test()` output could be explained as follows:

```
#include <arm_neon.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float32x4_t cross_test(const float32x4_t& lhs, const float32x4_t& rhs) {
  float32x4_t result;

  //   | f           | e
  // -----------------------------
  // 1 | a3(4) a2(3) | a1(2) a0(1)
  // 2 | b3(5) b2(6) | b1(7) b0(8)
  asm volatile (
    "vext.8 d6, %e1, %f1, #4"  "\n" // a2, a1
    "vext.8 d7, %e2, %f2, #4"  "\n" // b2, b1
    "vmul.f32 %e0, %f1, %e2"   "\n" // a3*b1, a2*b0
    "vmul.f32 %f0, %e1, d7"    "\n" // a1*b2, a0*b1
    "vmls.f32 %e0, %f2, %e1"   "\n" // a3*b1-a1*b3(18), a2*b0-a0*b2(18)
    "vmls.f32 %f0, %e2, d6"    "\n" // a1*b2-a2*b1(-9), a0*b1-a1*b0(-9)
    "vext.8 %e0, %f0, %e0, #4" "\n" // a2*b0-a0*b2(18), a1*b2-a2*b1(-9)
    : "+w"(result) // %0
    : "w"(lhs),    // %1
      "w"(rhs)     // %2
    : "d6", "d7"
  );

  return result;
}

#define nforeach(i, count) \
  for (int i = 0, __count = static_cast<int>(count); i < __count; ++i)

#define dump_f128(qf) do {                    \
  float *fp = reinterpret_cast<float *>(&qf); \
  puts(#qf ":");                              \
  nforeach(i, 4) {                            \
    printf("[%d]%f\n", i, fp[i]);             \
  }                                           \
} while (0)

int main() {
  float fa[] = {1., 2., 3., 4.};
  float fb[] = {8., 7., 6., 5.};

  float32x4_t qa, qb, qres;

  qa = vld1q_f32(const_cast<const float *>(&fa[0]));
  qb = vld1q_f32(const_cast<const float *>(&fb[0]));

  qres = cross_test(qa, qb);

  dump_f128(qa);
  puts("---");
  dump_f128(qb);
  puts("---");

  // -9, 18, -9, -9
  dump_f128(qres);

  return 0;
}
```